# How to save image in a Phone on clicking in React Native Expo Camera?

Tags: react-native, expo

This is what so far I have done. Here I am able to switch ON the camera and also get access to images using ImagePicker. But while clicking image, I am getting anything like where the image is saved and also I am unable to select the image properly. 
When I click pic on camera, I get this in console:

```
 "Object {
  "height": 4000,
  "uri": "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540himanshu717171%252FMyProject/Camera/373e905c-2ef8-4f0f-b4a4-78ac8a64732c.jpg",
  "width": 3000,
}"
```

And while selecting any image from Phone, I am getting this response in a console:

```
 "Object {
  "cancelled": false,
  "height": 721,
  "type": "image",
  "uri": "file:/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540himanshu717171%252FMyProject/ImagePicker/937bed14-dc51-4786-8836-09965b17d327.jpg",
  "width": 1280,
}"
```

This is my code. Please suggest me any changes required.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View ,TouchableOpacity,Platform, } from 'react-native';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import { FontAwesome, Ionicons,MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';




export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    hasPermission: null,
    cameraType: Camera.Constants.Type.back,
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.getPermissionAsync()
  }

  getPermissionAsync = async () => {
    // Camera roll Permission 
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        alert('Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!');
      }
    }
    // Camera Permission
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
    this.setState({ hasPermission: status === 'granted' });
  }

  handleCameraType=()=>{
    const { cameraType } = this.state

    this.setState({cameraType:
      cameraType === Camera.Constants.Type.back
      ? Camera.Constants.Type.front
      : Camera.Constants.Type.back
    })
  }

  takePicture = async () => {
    if (this.camera) {
      let photo = await this.camera.takePictureAsync();
      console.log(photo);

    }
  }

  pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images

    });
    console.log(result);
  }


  render(){
    const { hasPermission } = this.state
    if (hasPermission === null) {
      return <View />;
    } else if (hasPermission === false) {
      return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
    } else {
      return (
          <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Camera style={{ flex: 1 }} type={this.state.cameraType}  ref={ref => {this.camera = ref}}>
              <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:"row",justifyContent:"space-between",margin:30}}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={{
                    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent'                 
                  }}
                  onPress={()=>this.pickImage()}>
                  <Ionicons
                      name="ios-photos"
                      style={{ color: "#fff", fontSize: 40}}
                  />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={{
                    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                  }}
                  onPress={()=>this.takePicture()}
                  >
                  <FontAwesome
                      name="camera"
                      style={{ color: "#fff", fontSize: 40}}
                  />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={{
                    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                  }}
                  onPress={()=>this.handleCameraType()}
                  >
                  <MaterialCommunityIcons
                      name="camera-switch"
                      style={{ color: "#fff", fontSize: 40}}
                  />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </Camera>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }

}
App.navigationOptions = {   
    title: 'Camera',
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#ff6666',
    },
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      fontSize:20
    },
  };
```